# Angular2 How to submit a form without a page refesh

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, submit

I have a simple form  to send data to my component without the page refesh.

I have attempted to override the submit function by returning false but it fils to work as intended and the page is still refreshed.

html

```
        <form id="ngForm" [formGroup]="nameForm" (submit)="onSumbit()">
        <div style="padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;">
            <label>Name</label>
        </div>
        <input required  formControlName="name"></input>
        <div style="float:right; padding-top:2cm">
                <button form="ngForm">Search</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

typescript

```
onSubmit() {
    let user: UserInfo;

    user.name = 'test';
}
```

Comment: theres a typo in your code, unless you typed it wrong on here

Comment: use the button type submit `type="submit"`

Comment: also use `ngSubmit`

Answer (score 1):

Add a "type" attribute to your button:

```
<button type="button" form="ngForm">Search</button>
```